# C++: Broadcast/observer pattern with polymorphic events

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism, observer-pattern, extensibility

I'm currently trying to implement an event-system following a broadcast/observer scheme. I have events/notifications that contain information about **what** is happening:

```cpp
class Event
{
public:
    Event(const std::string& _name="event");
    ~Event() = default;

protected:
    std::string name;
};

/* I want to flexibly extend my Event base-class to accommodate for more involved behavior */
// example 
class InputEvent : public Event
{
public:
    InputEvent(const std::string& _name="input_event");
    ~InputEvent() = default;
    
    uint keycode; // or whatever...

};
```

and event handlers that manage **to whom** to broadcast these events and **what to do** if they themselves receive one:

```cpp
class EventHandler
{
public:
    EventHandler() = default;
    ~EventHandler() = default;
    
    /* React to incoming events (can/shall be overloaded for different subtypes of Event) */
    virtual void event_callback(const std::shared_ptr<Event> event);

    /* Broadcast events to recipients */
    template<typename EventType>
    void event_dispatch(const std::shared_ptr<EventType> event);
    
protected:
    // Addresses of all event recipients
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>> event_recipients;
    // Possible (???) implementation of event queue
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Event>> event_queue;
};
```

The `event_queue` acts as a buffer to store received events until they're scheduled to be processed by `event_callback`. However with my current implementation all of my events stored in this buffer will be upcasted into base-class `Event` pointers and thus render the overloads that different `EventHandler` derivatives may posses useless.

Is there a better container than a Queue or should I consider dynamic casting (and if so how)? Or do you have an altogether superior design in mind?

Answer (score 0):

## Double Dispatch

Or the visitor pattern.

Don't presume you understand the event, instead ask the event to describe itself to you.

```
class EventDispatch
{
    virtual ~EventDispatch() {}
    virtual void FooEvent(int) =0;
    virtual void BooEvent(Exception&) =0;
    virtual void ZooEvent(Animal&) =0;
    virtual void DirectEvent(DirectEvent&) =0;
};
class Event
{
    virtual ~Event() {}
    virtual void Dispatch(EventDispatch& dispatcher) =0;
}
class FooEvent : Event
{
   int data;
   void Dispatch(EventDispatch& dispatcher) { dispatcher.FooEvent(data); }
}
class DirectEvent: Event
{
   void Dispatch(EventDispatch& dispatcher) { dispatcher.DirectEvent(*this); }
}
```

This way later on a New event can be either mapped to one of the known descriptions. Or an event can be redesigned to describe itself differently. Without changing the dispatching implementation.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that whenever I create a new type of `Event` in the future, that can not be represented by the existing functions in the `EventDispatch` interface, that I would have to go back and make an addition there?

Comment: Yes, you would. but this shouldn't upset any of the other events as its a purely additive change.

Comment: What can I do if changing the `EventDispatch` interface isn't an option either?

Comment: Pass structured data. EG: xml, json, yaml, or any other data descriptive language. You can go one step further and pass an `interpreter` object when visiting the event. The interpreter can then be used like a state machine to process the structured data. Ignoring what it doesn't care about and responding to what it does. Note: this is quickly turning a light weight event into a heavy weight task.